# Datatables datetime format sorting problem

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I want to format the Date column. (DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm ) I also get an error in the order. Sorting does not work in this format.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the "DataTables plug-in for the jQuery?"

Comment: @Jesper yes I'm using.
When I convert the date column to the format I want, it doesn't work in sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Do you have the moment script linked to your HTML?

IF not be sure to add the following in the `<head>` tag of your html `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>`

IF so. You can do the following.

Instead of rendering it in columnDefs, you can actually reformat the date in the column initialization like so:

```js
moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;

var dataSet = [
{
"Something" : "Something1",
"Date" : "01/12/2021"
}
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { "data": "Something" },
            { "data": "Date",
            render: function(data, type, row) { //render function to format the date values from my AJAX 
                if (type === "sort" || type === "type") {
                    return data;
                }
                return moment(data).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm");
                }
                }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!--stylesheets-->
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css"> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.11.0/af-2.3.7/date-1.1.1/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.3/datatables.css"/>
      <!--scripts-->
      <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.11.0/af-2.3.7/date-1.1.1/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.3/datatables.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead class="thead-light">
               <tr>
                  <th>Something</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```